# pandas: How to return the count of string lengths of a string column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe `df`

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":["a", "b", "aa", "aaa", "bbb", "a"]})
```

in this case, I want to compute the count of the *string length of the column id*.

In this example, there 3 strings in `id` with length 1, and 1 string of length 2, 2 string of length 3. So I want to have a table that reflects this information

```
str_length  count
1           3
2           1
3           2
```

What's the most efficient way to do this for millions of rows?

This is the best I can come up with, but I heard that using `apply` is slow

```py
df_count = df.id.apply(lambda x: len(x)).value_counts()
df_count2 = pd.DataFrame({"str_length": df_count.index.tolist(), "count": df_count})
df_count2.sort_values("str_length")
```

which yields.

```
   str_length  count
1           1      3
2           2      1
3           3      2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go

```
df.id.str.len().value_counts()
1    3
3    2
2    1
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

A numpy solution:

```
np.transpose(np.unique(df.id.map(len), return_counts=True))

Out[229]:
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

---

Create DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(np.unique(df.id.map(len), return_counts=True)), 
             columns=['str_length', 'count'])

Out[231]:
   str_length  count
0           1      3
1           2      1
2           3      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use groupby and count.

```
(
    df.groupby(by=df.id.apply(len))
    .id.count()
    .to_frame('count')
    .rename_axis(index='str_length')
    .reset_index()
)

    str_length  count
0   1           3
1   2           1
2   3           2
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if performance is not the issue, we can use

```
df.id.groupby(lambda x: len(df.id[x])).size()
```

or

```
df.id.groupby(df.id.apply(len)).size()
```